# Style will not apply without using a ','

Tags: html, css

I just noticed, using the css code below ignores the .input.cmp bit :

```
.create input.cmp, input.email, input.pswd, input.pswda{}
```

while using the code below (with a , before) works fine.

```
.create ,input.cmp, input.email, input.pswd, input.pswda{}
```

How is this happening? Is this the right way to do it? Or am I doing something wrong here.

I previously used to use an ID instead of class and things worked fine without the first ','

Comment: `.create input.cmp` indicates an input tag of class `cmp` which resides somewhere inside a tag with class `create`.  Possibly not what you mean.  You should be more specific with what your expectation is, and what you're seeing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be like a misunderstanding and logical error .

1. `.create input.cmp,` selects `input.cmp` inside `.create`
2. `.create ,input.cmp,` are two different selectors `.create` and `input.cmp`

Here is an simple example:

`.create input.cmp` selects the input element ***ONLY*** in the following HTML

```
<div class="create">
   <input type="text" class="img" />
</div>
```

Where as, `.create ,input.cmp` selects both `div` and `input` elements.

Answer (score 2):

**.create input.cmp** said `input.cmp` inside `.create`.

Which you can write in HTML like this:

```
<div class="create">
 <input class="cmp">
</div>
```

&

**.create ,input.cmp** reflect different elements which styles are independent. In that **input.cmp** style is not depend on **.create** as per the above styling. So, you can use **input.cmp** inside or even outside of the **.create** With same styling.

Which you can write in HTML like this:

```
<div class="create"></div>
<input class="cmp">
```

**OR**

```
<div class="create">
 <input class="cmp">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.cls .subcls` refers to `.subcls` that is a child of `.cls`, whereas `.cls, .subcls` refers to **both** `.cls` and `.subcls`.